# JOIN two tables on unknown column and return that column name in the result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

**table_a** fields:

```
table_a_id
table_a_name
table_a_reg
```

| table_a_id | table_a_name | table_a_reg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **A1** | NAME_1 | REG_1 |
| **A2** | NAME_2 | REG_2 |
| **A3** | NAME_3 | REG_3 |

**table_b** fields:

```
table_b_id
table_b_name
table_b_set_1
table_b_set_2
table_b_set_3
```

`table_a_id` can be in a row (only ever in 1 row) in either `table_b_set_1`, `table_b_set_2` or `table_b_set_3`

| table_b_id | table_b_loc | table_b_set_1 | table_b_set_2 | table_b_set_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | LOC_1 | **A1** | Z1 | X1 |
| B2 | LOC_2 | Z2 | **A2** | X2 |
| B3 | LOC_3 | **A3** | Z3 | X3 |

I need to create a VIEW that shows:

```
table_a_id
table_a_name
table_a_reg
table_b_id
table_b_loc
```

AND I need to have an additional field in that VIEW tells which of `table_b_set_1`, `table_b_set_2` or `table_b_set_3` that `table_a_id` was in. So resulting VIEW would look like:

| table_a_id | table_a_name | table_a_reg | table_b_id | table_b_loc | table_b_set |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | NAME_1 | REG_1 | B1 | LOC_1 | table_b_set_1 |
| A2 | NAME_2 | REG_2 | B2 | LOC_2 | table_b_set_2 |
| A3 | NAME_3 | REG_3 | B3 | LOC_3 | table_b_set_1 |

So far I can select the data but only where I specify the `table_b_set` in the JOIN (and that limits me to only the data from that set only):

```
SELECT
    a.table_a_id, a.table_a_name, a.table_a_reg, b.table_b_id, b.table_b_loc
FROM
    (
    SELECT table_a_id, table_a_name, table_a_reg
    FROM tables_a
    ) a 
    JOIN table_b b ON a.table_a_id = b.table_b_set_1
```

To be honest I am stuck here and don't know whether I should be considering a different approach.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join using `in`:

```
SELECT a.table_a_id, a.table_a_name, a.table_a_reg,
       b.table_b_id, b.table_b_loc
FROM table_a a JOIN
     table_b b
     ON a.table_a_id IN (b.table_b_set_1, b.table_b_set_2, b.table_b_set_3);
```

For the last part, you can use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT a.table_a_id, a.table_a_name, a.table_a_reg,
       b.table_b_id, b.table_b_loc,
       (case when a.table_a_id = b.table_b_set_1 then 'table_b_set_1'
             when a.table_a_id = b.table_b_set_2 then 'table_b_set_2'
             when a.table_a_id = b.table_b_set_3 then 'table_b_set_3'
        end) as which   
FROM table_a a JOIN
     table_b b
     ON a.table_a_id IN (b.table_b_set_1, b.table_b_set_2, b.table_b_set_3);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. That is perfect for everything except the last part, which is: **AND I need to have an additional field that tells which of `table_b_set_1`, `table_b_set_2` or `table_b_set_3` that `table_a_id` was in**. Is that part even possible?

Comment: That's great... does exactly what I need. Really appreciate your help! Thank you!